# Write registry entries for retail Adobe Acrobat from instructions for Enterprise Edition

Tags: adobe-acrobat, software-activation

Here are the instructions for offline activation of the  the Enterprise version of Adobe Acrobat. https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/licensing.html See activation Exception 2. Can anyone use this information to write the registry entries for the offline activation of the retail version of Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Pretty much all the required information is there, one just have to decide which scripting language to use

Comment: Note that Super User is not a script writing service. It's fine if you try and get stuck, and ask how to proceed and maybe for an example; it's not fine if you ask us to do the work of writing a script for you.

Comment: I agree but my question was kicked out of stackoverflow. Here is the comment I received. "If you have a problem or a question about activation process you could post is on superuser.com but in the current state this question will not be acceptable even there. It is just not clear what is the problem"  here is the original post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508954/legacy-adobe-acrobat-activation-offline?noredirect=1#comment54801616_33508954 I thought I was in the correct forum, but they didn't. Now I don't know where to ask my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the short answer.

> **Adobe 9 and early Lifecycle have finished!!!.**

That means any service as:

1. **On-call Support.**
2. **E-mail Support.**
3. **Security Updates.**
4. **Patchs.**
5. **Activation Service.**
6. **Product Forum.**
7. **... etc.**

> **Are gone!!!**

Adobe strongly suggest to update to the lastest version:

---

> Adobe strongly recommends that customers update to the latest versions
>   of Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat. By updating installations to the
>   latest versions, customers benefit from the latest functional
>   enhancements and improved security measures.

---

There are a lot of ways to jump that activation proccess in whole internet but they are ***OUT OF THE SCOPE*** in **SuperUser** and any **Stack Exchange Networks**.

For more details you can check those references:

---

[Adobe Help Center - End of Support Acrobat 8 - 9](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/end-support-acrobat-8-reader.html)

[Adobe Policy Lifecycle](http://www.adobe.com/support/programs/policies/policy_enterprise_lifecycle.html)